# Creating a list of names and modification dates of files in a specific directory and make a dataframe out of it

Tags: python

I want to look at all files in a specific directory and get their name and modification date. I got the modification date. What I want to do is get the dates into a dataframe. So I can work with it. I want to get it into something like a pandas dataframe with one column called ModificationTime then the list of all the times.

I am using Jupyter notebooks and Python 3

```
import os
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict 


with os.scandir('My_Dir') as dir_entries:
    for entry in dir_entries:
        info = entry.stat()
        (info.st_mtime)
        time = (datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(info.st_mtime))
        df = {'ModificationTime': [time]}
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
        print(df1)

#Output is this
            ModificationTime
0 2019-02-16 02:39:13.428990
            ModificationTime
0 2019-02-16 02:34:01.247963
            ModificationTime
0 2018-09-22 18:07:34.829137


#If I print the code in a new cell I only get 1 output

print(df1) 

#Output is this
ModificationTime
0 2019-02-16 02:39:13.428990
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([])
with os.scandir('My_Dir') as dir_entries:
    for entry in dir_entries:
        info = entry.stat()
        (info.st_mtime)
        time = (datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(info.st_mtime))
        df = pd.DataFrame({'ModificationTime': [time]})
        df1 = df1.append(df)
```

This will solve the problem. In your code, you create a dataframe but you keep overwriting it so you only get one row in the final dataframe.

Comment: if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.